# Why does & get replaced with bogus text in sed replacement?

Tags: sed

in bash, i'm trying to use `sed` to replace a line of text in `xml` file.

```
line_item=jdbc:a_connector://localhost:2323/database?create=true&ampssl=true&ampsslMode=required
```

In the `xml` file, I have it something like:

```
...
<property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>{URL_TO_CHANGE}</value>
</property>
...
```

I tried to do `sed -e "s {URL_TO_CHANGE} $line_item " path/to/file.xml` note: using  (space) as the delimiter

however, the results is always: `jdbc:a_connector://localhost:2323/database?create=trueURL_TO_CHANGEamp;ssl=trueURL_TO_CHANGEamp;`

not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: You have to escape the `&` in the replacement because it means "recall the text which matched" to `sed`. Similarly, you'd need to backslash-escape any backslashes in the subtitution.